# Data structure choice for large, occassionally spliced lists

Tags: c++, data-structures

My situation is as follows. I have several (5-15) fairly long (~ 500,000) list of points of two floats each. I need to be able to quickly build them, iterate over them (doing calculations and either modifying or rebuilding them in the process), then splice them together at the end to get a single structure with all the points, which I will then have to iterate over.

What's a good choice of structure? `std::list` has a painfully slow `push_back` (it's my current solution, and building the lists is taking up 50% of my runtime), but `std::vector` and `std::deque` seem like they'd take forever to compile the final list.

EDIT: I forgot to mention - I'm going to need to sort each list at least once. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: `std::list::push_back()` should be O(1).

Comment: It's O(1), but it's a _slow_ O(1) - there's got to be a better way of doing this, people deal with much bigger datasets every time they run a 3D game.

Comment: Mind, I haven't exploited CUDA and the like yet, so that's not quite a fair comparison... but ideally I'd like to do this without requiring a GPU.

Comment: What do you mean by build them? How is this different from iterating them?

Comment: In practice `vector` often beats everything else because it is so cache-friendly. Have you timed the final step? And if you just need to iterate over the final result, why splice at all? Just write a smarter iterator.

Comment: A hash table? Quick insertion, and if any of your points are non-unique, then you'll know about it.

Comment: @AlanStokes Hm... that is an option, if I toss back a list of vectors or something. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @scott_fakename Hmm... maybe. With this many points I'm mildly worried about collisions, though.

Comment: @Dgrin91: As in, this is a simulation of a physical process, and I'm calculating the position of each point and then creating the lists from them.

Comment: Do you know the sizes of all vectors in advance (or are you able to make a good guess)? I guess not?

Comment: Hmm... Actually, yes I do. That's a good point; that should speed things up a bit.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 oh you're trying to avoid that. I only suggested it because I thought, with many points, knowing about duplicates would allow you to drop duplicates so you could save ram and computation time. But if you want to keep them then my thought obviously wouldn't work. Hmm...

Comment: No, I want to get rid of duplicates. I'm worried about hash collisions... though now that I think about it, I probably shouldn't  be, I don't have enough points yet. So that might be an option.

Comment: (Though there won't be very many duplicates.)

Comment: Oh - I need to sort every list at least once, by the way.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 Sounds like a rope data structure could be used, I would try and find one online and see if it helps.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 Also, a forward_list can gain you a bit more performance, if you don't need backwards iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact sizes of your vectors in advance, you can just create one big `vector` and then iterate over different parts of the big vector, for example:

```
std::vector<Point> data;
data.resize(totalSize); // totalSize is the sum of the sizes of the individual vectors
generatePart1(data.begin(), data.begin() + sizeOfPart1);
generatePart2(data.begin() + sizeOfPart1, data.begin() + sizeOfPart1 + sizeOfPart2);
// ...
iteratePart1(data.begin(), data.begin() + sizeOfPart1);
//...
//You don't need to splice the vectors now anymore, it's one big vector already.
```

If you can't know the exact sizes in advance, or don't like this approach, you can still use [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to reserve at least most of the storage in advance, and then use  a smart iterator that iterates over all the individual vectors in sequence to do the splicing.

Comment: Okay, this is weird. I'm using this method, but a) it's still taking rather long, and b) it's still giving me "External component has thrown an exception" and breaking in the middle of operator(new).

Comment: The line is labeled //report no memory, but I've got quite a bit of memory left _and_ I've reserved my memory in advance...

Comment: Okay, question - how long should it take, ish, to build a list of 2 million elements of two floats each? And if the answer is "more than a few seconds," is there a thread-safe version of `vector` anywhere?